# Why the shared printer from other PC name is not listed using php

Tags: php

I tried the following code to get the shared printers name:

```
$getprt=printer_list(PRINTER_ENUM_LOCAL| PRINTER_ENUM_SHARED );

$printers = serialize($getprt);
$printers = unserialize($printers);
//print_r($printers);
echo '<select name="printers">';
foreach ($printers as $PrintDest)
echo "<option value=".$PrintDest["NAME"].">".explode(",",$PrintDest["DESCRIPTION"])[1]."</option>";
echo '</select>';
```

But I didn't get the printer name shared by other PC in network.

[image]

I can get the printer list which are shared by my system only, not by others. I also tried with command prompt but that also not working.Anybody guide me to do this? Simply I'm asking that I want to get all the printers shared by all the PCs in a network.

Comment: well, you are asking only for printers shared on your local pc: `PRINTER_ENUM_SHARED: this parameter can't be used alone, it has to be OR'ed with other parameters, i.e. PRINTER_ENUM_LOCAL to detect the locally shared printers.`

Comment: Check out the other possible options on the documentation: http://php.net/manual/fa/function.printer-list.php

Comment: Please see the image i attached. When i executed the above comments i got all the shared printers name from my PC only, not from other PC.For example  my-PC is connected with Printer1, printer2. In the same network I connected with another PC named Another_PC which is attached with printer3. When i executed the above comments i only got Printer1,printer2 in a list not the othters. So any other function is available in php to all the printer list in network?

Comment: Share this printer checkbox is disabled in the image which i already attached. No not only for local PC all PCs in a network or shared printer i want to get. I don't know how to get it.

Comment: Again, please read the documentation. You explicitly ask to only list local printers that are shared. If you want other network printers, try the other parameters: `PRINTER_ENUM_CONNECTIONS`, `PRINTER_ENUM_NETWORK`, `PRINTER_ENUM_REMOTE`

Comment: Hi Gerald, Yah you are correct. In my documentation, I wrongly did it. In a network , many printers are connected  at the mean time my pc may contain some printer. I want to get the list of printers in entire printers name which are shared in network. And also i tried other parameter:  PRINTER_ENUM_CONNECTIONS, PRINTER_ENUM_NETWORK, PRINTER_ENUM_REMOTE. But i couldn't sove the problem till now. Or otherwise i want to get the printer name which drives are installed in printers and faxes. Anyway i need solution that to know the printers name in active shared environment.

Comment: @SaranPHP:Did you get any solution?